# Remove user control and redraw?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, graph

I have a Graph as user control and I'm trying to redraw the graph.
Why does this not work if i want to redraw the user control?

```
userGraph.Dispose();
new UserControls.Graph();
```

Shouldn't it dispose the whole graph and redraw the user control and initialize all the components?

Comment: You should to provide a method that will refresh the data/display of the graph. Creating a new control is awkward. If you want to refresh the graphic display only- call `graph.Invalidate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be another way to redraw your control, like update its data source or manually update its content - you should check its code or documentation.

But if you want to remove control from the form you should use

```
myForm.Controls.Remove(userGraph); //assuming that control is on the form
```

And if you want to add new control, then it should look like this:

```
UserControls.Graph newGraph = new UserControls.Graph();
//initialization of your new graph
myForm.Controls.Add(newGraph );
```

Here is example from msdn: [Control.ControlCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)